# Selecting parts of a number and checking lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have made this knowledge base from information provided in the question:

```
student(jill,12071992,computer_science,[tennis,lacrosse]).
student(joe,14021993,mathematics,[tennis,rugby,football]).
```

Which represents, the students name, their birth date, their subject, and the sports they play.

Question 1 -

`born_before(N,Y) -` student named N was born before year Y

```
born_before(N,Y):-student(N,____X,_,_), Y > X.
```

obviously the above doesn't work, my problem is i don't know how to segregate the YYYY from DDMMYYYY term in prolog, to then set it to X, so it can be compared to the Y value.

Question 2 -

`plays_sport(N,S) -` student named N plays sport S.

my attempt

```
plays_sport(N,S):-student(N,_,_,[S|Sx]), plays_sport(N,Sx).
```

this always returns false. I have tried to use tail recursion so that the sport can be matched from the lists of sports in the knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of your question you could write rules to extract the year, the month, and the day from an integer representing the date in the ddmmyyyy format, like this:

```
extract_year(DDMMYYYY, YYYY) :- YYYY is mod(DDMMYYYY, 10000).
extract_day(DDMMYYYY, DD) :- DD is DDMMYYYY // 1000000.
extract_month(DDMMMYYYY, MM) :- DDMM is DDMMMYYYY // 10000, MM is mod(DDMM, 100).
```

`//` operator represents integer division, when the fractional part is dropped from the answer. `mod/3` is an operation for finding the remainder of integer division.

You could then combine them back into yyyymmdd format, and compare as integers ([demo](http://ideone.com/QDLqef)).

For your second part, you could use [`memberchk(Element, List)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=memberchk/2) to check if the desired sport is present in the list:

```
plays_sport(N,S) :- student(N,_,_,AllSports), memberchk(S, AllSports).
```